# Loop - control flow for working with 2 lists of unknown length

Tags: c#, control-flow

Suppose 2 list of strings of unknown, possibly different length. 
Items in the second list must be matched to the items in the first list, but the matching may depend on the content of the following items:

**List lst_1:**
*[0] Apple
[1] Orange
[2] Peach
[3] ...*

**List lst_2:**
*[0] salt
[1] tequila
[2] honey
[3] vodka
[4] whisky
[5] ...*

Items in lst_1 must be matched with items in lst_2 based on several conditions. For instance, for each fruit, there must be at least one alcohol; whiskey can not be matched with peach; there must be less than 5 alcohols in any given cocktail, etc.

If I match Apple with salt and tequila, orange with honey and vodka, I get peach with whisky, which breaks one of the conditions... but if I put apple, tequila and honey together, I get Orange-Vodka-Whiskey, which is a valid drink.

Bottom line, I need to loop through both lists, each time checking a number of conditions for the current item as well as what it means for the next item on the list and for the previous item, and I might need to back track several times and fix things until everything matches properly.

I was thinking of a big `while(bNotReady){...}` loop like this:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
string fruit, additive;
bool bContainsAlcohol = false;
dictionary<string, string> dic = new dictionary<string,string>();
while(bNotReady){
  fruit = lst_1[i];
  additive = lst_2[j];
  if (is_valid_match(fruit,additive) && bContainsAlcohol)
  {
     dic.Add(fruit,additive);
     i++; j++;
     continue;
  }
  else if(...)

}
```

And working my way through the lists, but I can see this would quickly become one huge, unreadable loop.

Is there a better way to work out the control flow for this task?

Comment: This is a job for constraint programming!

Comment: Since it doesn't sounds like e.g. `Apple` can only be used once and you probably don't have meeelions of each, I would just do something like `for( int fruit = 0; fruit < fruitCount; fruit++) for (int additive = 0; additive < additiveCount; additive++) { if (is_valid_match(fruit, additive))...}`.

Comment: @presiuslitelsnoflek I am not familiar with constraint programming. I had a quick look on Google and it seems interesting, but I found very little in way of practical examples. How would you go about solving the little problem above using constraint programming?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Actually, each entry can be used just the once in the set sequence, which is why it needs to take into account the items that come after. I can't just make all possible combinations and reject those which are illegal. Also, this question has been simplified to illustrate the kind of relationships between the two lists and see what approaches can be used without writing into pages and pages of specification, however we are talking about lists containing tens of thousands of elements, not just a handful.

Comment: I can't really go much into explaining constraint programming, as it is a *huge* domain of computer science. But here are the basics and why I think it's the perfect tool for your problem: constraint programming is about entering a set of *constraints* (there must be at least one alcohol, whiskey doesn't go with peach, and so on), in a formal way, and submitting these constraints to a *solver* that will find the acceptable solutions for you. In other words, you are currently trying to write a constraint solver.

Comment: If you want to use C#, you could take a look at [Microsoft Solver Foundation Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff826354(v=vs.93).aspx) (I've never used it), or use a language more suited to the task such as Prolog. I'm afraid I can't go much deeper into details as it is really a *huge* area, but one that will solve your problem indeed.

Comment: In case you're still working on your problem, [here's a few examples in Prolog](http://eclipseclp.org/examples/index.html) on constraint programming. [This one in particular](http://eclipseclp.org/examples/zebra.ecl.txt) is analogous to yours.

Comment: @Sylverdrag Did you have a chance to test constraint programming for your problem? Or did you find a way to do it natively?

Comment: @samy Sorry, I am traveling ATM. Looking at the answers, I realized there is a requirement I didn't not explain correctly and which does not fit constraint programming nor your solution: The sequence of the ingredients is important. It's not just a bunch of ingredients to be matched against some rules, but the ingredients sequence must be "mostly" matched - can't just take ingredient 15 and match it with ingredient 2 then 3 and 8... Imagine ingredients are on a carrier belt: you can skip ahead a bit, but can't skip back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to go for the constraint programming path i think that it would be a better idea, yet you can do it with brute force and .Net collections. It won't be pretty but it should work.

- First, you need a way to enumerate all the possible partitions of your additives into sets with a cardinality equal to the number of ingredients. [a,b,c] partitioned into three sets could give `[abc,,]` then `[ab,c,]` then `[a,bc,]`, etc..
- Enumerating all these sets you would need to enumerate all the permutations of these sets
- Finally, for each permutation of a set you would need to check whether all the rules are satisfied by the current match between ingredient and set of additives

I didn't have time to create a method for the partitioning but i had a permutation extension available so i created the second step of the program

```
private static IList<string> Ingredients { get; set; }
private static IList<string> Additives { get; set; }
private static IList<Func<string, string, bool>> Rules { get; set; }

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Ingredients = new List<string>() { "Apple", "Orange", "Peach" };
    Additives = new List<string>() { "Vodka", "Rum", "Whiskey" };
    Rules = new List<Func<string, string, bool>>() { (ingredient1, ingredient2) => { return (ingredient1 != "Peach" && ingredient2 != "Whiskey"); } };
    var additivesOrganisationMatchingAllTheRules = FindMatch();
}

private static IList<string> FindMatch()
{
    // here we should enumerate all sets and then enumerate permutation of all the sets
    // instead for the example we just enumerate the permutations
    foreach (var additivesPermutation in Additives.GetCombinations())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < additivesPermutation.Count; i++)
        {
            var thisSituationIsOk = Rules.All(r => r(Ingredients[i], Additives[i]));
            if (thisSituationIsOk) return additivesPermutation;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

It uses a permutation method extension; from what i can remember this extension doesn't preserve the initial list. Don't use without tests

```
public static class CombinatorialExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<IList<TSource>> GetCombinations<TSource>(
        this IList<TSource> source)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        }
        return GetCombinationsImpl<TSource>(source);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<IList<TSource>> GetCombinationsImpl<TSource>(
        this IList<TSource> list)
    {
        return Permutations(list, list.Count);
    }

    private static void ShiftRight<TSource>(IList<TSource> list, int cardinality)
    {
        var lastElement = list[cardinality - 1];
        list.RemoveAt(cardinality - 1);
        list.Insert(0, lastElement);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<IList<TSource>> Permutations<TSource>(IList<TSource> list, int cardinality)
    {
        if (cardinality == 1)
        {
            yield return list;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < cardinality; i++)
            {
                foreach (var perm in Permutations(list, cardinality - 1))
                    yield return perm;
                ShiftRight(list, cardinality);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

This algorithm would let you find a solution that matches the ingredients and rules you have, but it is not very pretty, and really really not efficient: many combinations would be computed multiple times. You would also have to tweak the rules to get results that would be pleasant (ie minimum and maximum number of additives, etc)

---

**EDIT**

It is even possible to avoid having to create all the sets, you can simply add as many separators into your additives as you have ingredients minus 1 . Then just do the permutation and split your additives according to the separators into lists of additives. Then your rules can take an ingredient and a list of additives as a basis to check if it is respected. Here is some sample code

```
private static IList<string> Ingredients { get; set; }
private static IList<string> Additives { get; set; }
private static IList<Func<string, IList<string>, bool>> Rules { get; set; }

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Ingredients = new List<string>() { "Apple", "Orange", "Peach" };
    Additives = new List<string>() { "Vodka", "Rum", "Whiskey" };
    Additives.Add("Separator");
    Additives.Add("Separator"); // add as many separators as the number of ingredients - 1
    Rules = new List<Func<string, IList<string>, bool>>() {
        (ingredient1, ingredient2) => { return (ingredient1 != "Peach" && ingredient2.All(s => s != "Whiskey")); }
        , 
        (ingredient1, ingredient2) => { return ingredient2.Count > 0; }
    };
    var additivesOrganisationMatchingAllTheRules = FindMatch();
}

private static IList<IList<string>> FindMatch()
{
    // separators will create the sets
    foreach (var additivesPermutation in Additives.GetCombinations())
    {
        var Sets = Split(additivesPermutation);
        var thisSituationIsOk = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < Sets.Count && thisSituationIsOk ; i++)
        {
            thisSituationIsOk = thisSituationIsOk && Rules.All(r => r(Ingredients[i], Sets[i]));
        }
        if (thisSituationIsOk) return Sets;
    }
    return null;
}

private static IList<IList<string>> Split(IList<string> values)
{
    var splitValues = new List<IList<String>>();
    var currentList = new List<string>();
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        if (value == "Separator")
        {
            splitValues.Add(currentList);
            currentList = new List<string>();
        }
        else
        {
            currentList.Add(value);
        }
    }
    splitValues.Add(currentList);
    return splitValues;
}
```